# Can Chromecast run Native C libraries?

Tags: google-cast

As I understand it, Chromecast runs a modified version of ChromeOS.
Hackers examining the device have "concluded that it’s more Android than Chrome OS," adding, "to be specific, it’s actually a modified Google TV release, but with all of the Bionic / Dalvik stripped out and replaced with a single binary for Chromecast."

With this in mind can one conclude that Chromecast can only run HTML/JS code and that it can't run any Native C code?

What if I have a Native C library which already runs on Android and iOS, what will be the best approach to port it so that it could be run on Chromecast?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no provision for supporting a native application.